# PowerShell cmdlet Install-WindowsFeature called from C# errors and is not listed in the collections of commands

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to install new features on a Windows Server 2012 system through PowerShell and C#. I am getting this error back when trying to call the `Install-WindowsFeature` cmdlet:

> The term 'Install-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...

I can call other cmdlets though C# and even some of the other new ones. I did a `Get-Command` and `Install-WindowsFeature`, `Remove-WindowsFeature`, and `Get-WindowsFeatures` are not listed...but about 980 others are.

Why wouldn't I be able to call this cmdlet from my C# program, but when I go to PowerShell it calls it just fine?

```
runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Install-WindowsFeature");
Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Comment: What module is that in? Maybe it is in a module that is not imported by in default with that overload of `CreateRunspace`. You can add ps modules to the `InitialSessionState` object that you pass to a different overload of `CreateRunspace`.

Comment: It is in the ServerManager module. I've never used the InitialSessionState object, I will have to look into that.

Comment: @mikez  Tried your suggestion, still a no go.

string[] modules = { "ServerManager" };

InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(modules);

runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);

Comment: @Matronix: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command instead of Install-WindowsFeature in your code:

> Invoke-Expression "Powershell -Command {Import-Module ServerManager ; Install-WindowsFeature XXXX}"

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling in x64. In Visual Studio go to menu *Project* → *Properties* → *Build - Platform Target* = x64.